# How to fix '[WARNING] The callable Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.InverseMod has been deprecated.' warning in Q#?

Tags: q#

In IntegerFactorization Q# sample in [Microsoft/Quantum repository](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/samples/algorithms/integer-factorization), there isn't InverseMod function. But when I compile and run the code, it produces a number of warnings "The callable Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.InverseMod has been deprecated in favor of Microsoft.Quantum.Math.InverseModI.". How can I fix it?

There is no word `InverseMod` anywhere in Shor.qs file.

I expect warning is disappear. Plese help me TT

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the use of the deprecated function `InverseMod` in arithmetic libraries used by the IntegerFactorization project.

The project has dependencies on several NuGet packages, among them `Microsoft.Quantum.Standard` which provides standard library functions, including modular arithmetic. This package used the deprecated function in its version 0.6.1905.301, which caused this runtime warning. If you check the source code of the package in [Microsoft/QuantumLibraries](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/) repository, you'll notice that this has been fixed [two days ago](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/pull/99/), so with the next release of the NuGet package this warning will disappear.

**Edit:** This should be fixed in release 0.7.1905.3109. The samples repository has been updated to use the new release; if you get the latest version of the repository and try running the project again the warning should go away.